# when I digit a bucket name that already exists Im not having an error

Tags: amazon-s3

I have this function below to create a new bucket.

When I digit a bucket name that already exist I got an error.

But when I digit a bucket name that I already have in my account I dont have any error, its normal?

```
def createBucket(bucketName):
    c = boto.s3.connect_to_region("us-east-1")
    bucket = c.create_bucket(bucketName)

bucket = createBucket(raw_input("Bucket name: "))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the specs from [Boto](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/s3_tut.html#creating-a-bucket)

> The create_bucket method will create the requested bucket if it does
>   not exist or will return the existing bucket if it does exist.

Hence, when you try to "create" a bucket with a name that already exists, the reference to the same bucket is returned and no new bucket is created.

Comment: Ok...so its normal! Thank you